# How to fix "Error : object ‘as_tibble’ is not exported by 'namespace:dplyr' ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘BLANK’" in R

Tags: r, package, installation

Whenever I try to install any packages in R I now get this error. This didn't used to happen and is new within the last month and seems to be ubiquitous across all packages I try to install.

I am using R studio but the error occurred when I tried to use just R alone, as well. Currently trying to install rscopus package but the error occurs with most all packages I have tried to install.

Thanks.

Console:

```
installing the source package ‘rscopus’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rscopus_0.6.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 40422 bytes (39 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 39 KB

Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018i.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
* installing *source* package ‘rscopus’ ...
** package ‘rscopus’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : object ‘as_tibble’ is not exported by 'namespace:dplyr'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rscopus’
* removing 
‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rscopus’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rscopus’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in ‘/private/var/folders/wz/p_wg38vx11vcp94hhcw5dv_w0000gn/T/RtmpaJeH3b/downloaded_packages’
```

Sessioninfo()

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.1

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] tibble_1.3.4      DescTools_0.99.21 dplyr_0.5.0       car_2.1-4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.11       magrittr_1.5       splines_3.3.2      MASS_7.3-45        lattice_0.20-34
 [6] R6_2.2.0           rlang_0.1.6        minqa_1.2.4        tools_3.3.2        nnet_7.3-12
[11] parallel_3.3.2     pbkrtest_0.4-6     grid_3.3.2         nlme_3.1-128       mgcv_1.8-15
[16] quantreg_5.29      DBI_0.5-1          MatrixModels_0.4-1 lme4_1.1-12        assertthat_0.1
[21] manipulate_1.0.1   Matrix_1.2-7.1     nloptr_1.0.4       boot_1.3-18        expm_0.999-2
[26] mvtnorm_1.0-6      SparseM_1.74       foreign_0.8-67

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with similar issues, I updated to the newest version of R and it seemed to solve the problem.

Thinking back to the origin of the problem, it coincided with updated to OS X Mojave.